# Is there a way to download Vimeo clips to mp4 etc. without logging-in

Tags: c#, .net, video-streaming, webclient, vimeo

I want to download vimeo files using `WebClient` to mp4 or so, is there a way to extract the video link from the swf flash object?

I don't have a vimeo account, is that necessary? I prefer not to use the vimeo API at all, if there is  a RESTful or http way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You must be logged in and can only download them on vimeo.com if the uploader allows it.